# Get the OpenGL object position in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new in OpenGL. I created an OpenGL object and display it on the screen. I wan to ask how to get the position of the OpenGL object ?

Because I want to detect whether the OpenGL object is being collided with others objects or not.

So, how do I get the position (point x, point y) of the OpenGL object in Android.

Comment: There is no such thing as a OpenGL object. If this is class written by you, then please show it.

Comment: @BDL: To be completely correct, there *are* OpenGL objects: buffer objects, texture objects, etc. But they do not have a "position", so it's likely that these are not what he's talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Look into model view project matrices...

The model matrix represents the position of object in 3d space

It's just an abstract view..there is no such thing as position of object in openGL at last
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Answer (score 0):

To see if objects are colliding do following.
1. Create axis aligned bounding box to object you are drawing this is nothing but xy extent of your object.
2. Then test if any two axis aligned bounding boxes intersects each other . There lots of material online available on this. You can do this tests in shaders also.
3.If they AABB intersect your object collide.

For more precise collision detection you might want to use sphere or ellipsoid as bounding volume.
Only care you have to take is keep bounding box updated and axis aligned if your object is continuously moving.

Hope this helps.